# TagSuggest validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate custom suggest tag, i have found on github, used in dynamic html table. Now the scenario is i want to validate the html table on button click, I'm validating all the input controls in each row (it contains suggesttag, input and select). I'm able to get the error message on input controls except on suggesttag.
Any guidance will be appreciated :)

SuggestTag url https://gist.github.com/goyalzz/3e4923c14825021c77d49b7b3322a90b

```js
function validTable() {
            $('#sample_editable_1 tr').each(function (i, row) {
                debugger;
                var $row = $(row);
                    $testCode = $row.find('input[name*="code"]'),
                    $testName = $row.find('input[name*="testname"]'),
                    $testStatus = $row.find('input[name*="status"]'),
                    $testCollectDate = $row.find('input[name*="collecttime"]'),
                    $testNotes = $row.find('input[name*="notes"]'),
                    $testSpecimenType = $row.find('input[name*="specimen"]'),
                    $testDx = $row.find('input[name*="diagnosis"]');



                if ($testCode.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Lab Test Code.");
                    return false;
                }
                if ($testName.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Lab Test Name.");

                    return false;
                }
                if ($testStatus.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Lab Test Status.");

                    return false;
                }
                if ($testCollectDate.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Lab Test Collection Date.");

                    return false;
                }
                if ($testNotes.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Lab Test Note.");
                    return false;
                }
                if ($testSpecimenType.val() == 0) {
                    alert("Plese Select Specimen Type.");

                    return false;
                }
                if ($testDx.val() == "") {
                    alert("Enter Diagnosis Code.");

                    return false;
                }


            });
        }
```